# HTTPS (SSL) get request with NodeMCU

Tags: ssl, https, lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I would like to perform GET requests to googleapi.com with my ESP8266 running NodeMCU, to get some data from the google Calendar API. The website allows only secured connection (HTTPS/SSL).

First, I've been trying to connect to google.com (secured) to give it a try, but with no success either. Here is the LUA code:

```
conn=net.createConnection(net.TCP, 1)
conn:on("receive", function(sck, c) print(c) end )
conn:on("connection", function(conn)
      print("connected")
      conn:send("HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\n".. 
             "Host: google.com\r\n"..
             "Accept: */*\r\n"..
             "User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; esp8266 Lua;)"..
             "\r\n\r\n") 
end )
conn:on("disconnection", function(conn)  print("disconnected") end )
conn:connect(443,"google.com")
```

Nothing is triggered (not even the "connected").

I also downloaded the *latest* version of nodemcu (master branch) from the website http://nodemcu-build.com by selecting the SSL support.

```
NodeMCU custom build by frightanic.com
    branch: master
    commit: c8037568571edb5c568c2f8231e4f8ce0683b883
    SSL: true
```

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Someone reported the problem on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/esp8266/comments/2zt58x/does_ssl_work/), but no final solution given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The required fix for the `net` module is not yet available on the master branch. [PR 1014](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/pull/1014) was only merged to the dev branch in early February.

The dev branch has an HTTP client module with which your code can be shortened to a one-liner. See http://nodemcu.readthedocs.org/en/dev/en/modules/http/#httpget for details.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Indeed the `http.get()` function works perfectly.

Comment: The HTTP solution works for me too. Is there any update on using the NodeMCU Net Module? I feel that establishing a connection and making requests will allow the chip to make more ssl requests faster than renegotiating the connection via the http.post command.

Comment: @JoeAndolina you may follow https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/issues/1146